# regular expressions for one sentence per line

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to take a text area value and run it through regular expression to split it to lines.

so if someone wrote a line then enter and another line and enter the i will have an array with each line per array value

The expression I've came up with so far is :

```
 (.+?)\n|\G(.*)
```

and this is how i use it(from a website i use to test expressions http://myregextester.com/)

```
 $sourcestring="
 this is a sentense yeaa
 interesting sentense
 yet another sentese
 ";
 preg_match_all('/(.+?)\n|\G(.*)/',$sourcestring,$matches);
 echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
```

however there is 1 object in the array that always empty and i am trying to find a way to get rid of it.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: i didnt thought about explode now that nickb suggested it i will probably do however still concerned about the last line

Comment: If you end up with an empty string, ignore it.

Comment: Thanks very much everyone. i will explode with trim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this, just use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode), like so:

```
$lines = explode( "\n",  trim( $input));
```

Now each line of the user's `$input` will be a single array entry in `$lines`.

Comment: nickb will that also split the last row that didnt had a \n in ?

Comment: @tigrang - Sorry, I didn't realized you fixed that too - I was testing this on codepad and realized I could consolidate `array_filter( $lines, function( $el) { return strlen( trim( $el)) > 0; } );` to just `trim()` since the extra whitespace characters are at the beginning and end. However, `array_filter()` would be necessary if there were blank lines in between. :)

Comment: That is true, didn't think of that. I just made it work for the example data he gave :)

Answer (score 1):

This will do and get rid of the empty lines in the beginning and end of the array

```
explode("\n", trim($sourcestring));
```

See example: http://viper-7.com/pNqtvV

Answer (score 0):

There are various types of newlines. In HTML form context you'll typically receive `CR` `LF` for line endings. A dumb explode will do, but a regex will catch all variations if you use `\R`. Thus `\r\n` and `\n` or `\r` and others will be processed by:

```
 $lines = preg_split(':\R:', $text);
```

[`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) is the equivalent to PHPs explode(). So you don't need to use `preg_match_all`.